# Does the 'private' access modifier give the compiler more room for optimization?

Tags: c++, oop, private

Does it allow the compiler to inline it, knowing that only functions in the same class can access it? Or is it only for the programmer's convenience?

Comment: Any decent compiler will inline a non-virtual method when it can and when it makes sense.  Doesn't have anything to do with the accessibility since that doesn't modify the method implementation.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question last week. I could not think of any example where the compiler would generate different code because a function is private. Any examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler *can* (but is not required to) optimize as you suggest, but that's not the *point*.  The point of access modifiers is to catch certain classes (no pun intended) of programming errors at compile time.  Private functions are functions that, if someone called them from outside the class, that would be a *bug*, and you want to know about it as early as possible.

(Any time you ask the question "could the compiler make optimizations based on this information available to it", the answer is "yes, unless there's a specific rule in the standard that says it's not allowed to" (such as the rules for `volatile`, whose entire purpose is to inhibit optimizations).  However, compilers do not necessarily *bother* optimizing based on any given piece of information.  There is, after all, no requirement for compilers to do any optimization in the first place!  How clever your compiler is, nowadays, largely depends on how long you are willing to let it run; MSVC's whole-program PGO mode is capable of inlining *through virtual method dispatch* -- it guesses the most likely target, and falls back to a regular virtual call at runtime if the guess was wrong -- but slows down compiles by at least a factor of two.)

Comment: Just to add that the only good reason to make a method inline is that it is small enough. It has nothing to do with from where it is called.

Comment: Can you give one example of how the compiler could use the fact that a function is private to generate different code, optimized in any way?

Comment: @JohnPS: The set of functions that can access a public member is infinite, but a compiler can enumerate all functions that access a given private member. This doesn't impact inlining directly, but does allow a compiler to prove that no non-inlined version is necessary.

Comment: @MSalters: That's true if all members are defined in the same compilation unit, but if one is not, then the compiler needs to generate all the private members so that they can be linked to later, no? Either way, this doesn't seem to make code faster, just reduce the code size, and doesn't seem to offer any advantage over "whole program optimization."

Comment: If not all members are in the same compilation unit, the compiler can generate potentially-unnecessary functions in discardable sections so the linker throws them away when they're found to be unnecessary. And reduced code size equals better cache utilization equals faster code; one of the standard things to do with profile-directed optimization, these days, is optimize *only* the hottest parts of the program for speed, and everything else for size.

Comment: In this case, the linker would throw them away if they were public or private, so being private doesn't offer any advantage in this regard.

Comment: Not true; if they're public, the linker has to preserve them against the possibility that code that *does* use them will materialize at load time.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a stand alone program. A library would have to keep code for the public members. But if they are never called, they generally won't end up in the cache, so I don't see there being a slow down from this.

Answer (score 4):

The access specifiers are a part of C++ mechanism to implement OOP principles of Encapsulation and Abstraction and not optimization for compilers.

Some intelligent compiler can possibly implement some optimization through it but it not enforced to do so by the C++ Standard. The purpose of access specifiers is not Optimization but to facilitate language constructs for principles supported by the C++ language.